# MahApp Flyout CloseCommand and IsOpen are Not Binding Properly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I'm following a strict MVVM pattern.

In my `FlyoutControl`, I've bound the following:

```
    <controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <controls:Flyout IsOpen="{Binding FlyoutIsOpen, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         CloseCommand="{Binding CloseFlyoutCommand}">
            ...
        </controls:Flyout>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
```

I have two scenarios, both which do not work:

---

Scenario 1:

> I set `FlyoutIsOpen` to `true` in my `ViewModel` constructor, and I bind by `CloseFlyoutCommand` to a `DelegateCommand` which accepts a method that sets `FlyoutIsOpen` to `false`.

In this scenario, my view loads with the `Flyout` already open (as expected). However, when I click the `Flyout` close button, nothing happens unless I click it again. If I print the output of my method, I can confirm that the command sets `FlyoutIsOpen` to `false`, but for some reason, I require a second click (after `FlyoutIsOpen` is set to `false`) to actually close the `Flyout`.

---

Scenario 2:

> I set `FlyoutIsOpen` to `false` (or uninitialized) in my constructor. I bind another button to a `DelegateCommand` which accepts a method that sets `FlyoutIsOpen` to `true`.

The view loads with the `Flyout` closed (as expected). However, when I click a button that I've bound to a method that sets `FlyoutIsOpen` to `true`, nothing happens and the `Flyout` does not appear.

---

Has anyone experienced similarly non-responsive issues with the `FlyoutsControl`? If so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: which MVVM framework are you using?

Comment: @punker76 Shouldn't really matter though. It's just `INPC` and I feel like something within the `MahApps` is preventing it. Haven't had a chance to look at the source code yet.

Comment: Hi @Bryant, running into the same problem now. Did you ever manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @Bryant This should be fixed with latest pre-release and maybe already with latest stable.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems binding the `isOpen` property, but I managed by styling the `ItemContainer` and binding `IsOpen` there instead of inside my `Flyout`. I don'T even need the `CloseCommand` anymore, setting `Visible` to false in my viewmodel closes the flyout.

The `MainWindow.xaml` where I define the `ItemContainer` Bindings:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <controls:FlyoutsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Flyouts}">
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.Resources>
            <view:FlyoutPositionConverter x:Key="FlyoutPositionConverter"/>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.Resources>
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
                <view:SettingsFlyout/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:Flyout}}"
               TargetType="{x:Type controls:Flyout}">
                <Setter Property="Header"
                    Value="{Binding Header}" />
                <Setter Property="IsOpen"
                    Value="{Binding Visible}" />
                <Setter Property="Position"
                    Value="{Binding Position, Converter={StaticResource FlyoutPositionConverter}}" />
                <Setter Property="IsModal"
                    Value="{Binding IsModal}" />
                <Setter Property="Theme" Value="Accent" />
            </Style>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

The mainviewmodel has a `ObservableCollection<IFlyoutViewModel>` named `Flyouts` and contains all my flyout viewmodels. They of course have to implement `IFlyoutViewModel`:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApplication.ViewModel
{
    internal interface IFlyoutViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string Header { get; }
        bool Visible { get; set; }
        Position Position { get; set; }
        bool IsModal { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Position
    {
        Top,
        Left,
        Right,
        Bottom
    }
}
```

The `FlyoutPositionConverter` is just a mapper between my position enum and the `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Position` because I didn't want to use the real positon in my viewmodel interface.

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post. Alternatively, tailor this to be a self-contained answer for the specific question being asked.

Comment: ok, I'll replace it with a complete answer based on the other as soon as i can